# UIView at bottom UIScrollView does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get an `UIScrollView` working with my Storyboard. It works but the `UIView` at the bottom that I use with a gesture tap for getting back is not showing. How can this be?

So everything works expect that. This are the things that I did:

- Set freeform in Storyboard
- Disable auto layout for the Storyboard nib
- Changed the freeform dimensions to `X:320 Y:800`
- Dragged some labels and stuff in the Scrollview
- Created an outlet for the ScrollView
- Enabled scroll programmatically
- Enabled Contentsize CGMakeSize() programmatically;

So I normally did everything, why isn't my UIView showing up at `Y:750`. The only thing I do with the `UIView` is setting the `Background/CornerRadius`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be if your `UIView` is no included in the calculation for the content size. Other than that I cannot see anything obvious.

Comment: If I put something next to the UIView, like an other object (UIlabel/Switch/slider) that will show up, but not the UIView that I want.

Comment: I suppose you have tried the old trick to alter background colour of the view and made sure that it is not hidden. Sorry I cannot be more helpful.